# Node Express Postgres App.Post Syntax error

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

**Currently receiving the following error when trying to pass variables to postgres db:**

*Error: syntax error at or near ","*

```
  const rb = req.body;
  const sql= "insert into test1 (user, name, created) values (?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"
  pool.query(sql, [rb.user, rb.name], (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');

    }
  });
});
```

When I remove [rb.user, rb.name] and hardcode the variables, it goes through.  Any ideas/possibly an oversight on my end?

Comment: Change the “?, ?” By “$1,$2”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi According to the documentation below

https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query

Your query should be like below. You should be using `$1` & `$2` instead of `?`

```js
const rb = req.body;
  const sql= "insert into test1 (user, name, created) values ($1, $2, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);"
  pool.query(sql, [rb.user, rb.name], (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error: ' + err);
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');

    }
  });
});
```